# i want to partition from that 512gb drive on SSD

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

i bought hp spectre x360 laptop
in laptop i got 512 GB SSD drive and windows  pre-installed in it
only c: drive is there i want to partition from that 512gb drive of ssd with proper way without loss of speed of ssd
please help me for that

Answer (score 1):

go to computer management it will load a MMC console select disk management from the console then right click on your C:\ and click on shrink, here you can provide the size you required for your next drive.

Comment: is it same way to do before we did with HDD

Comment: Yes, it is........